# Qt QGraphicsView or QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

For a school project we need to make the game [Puerto Rico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rico_%28board_game%29) in Qt. I was looking at QGraphicsView to display the gameboard, but it seems that this was a lot harder than i tought and had a lot of functions i don't need. So now my question is it also possible to achieve something like a gameboard using only label and display pictures in them?

Comment: That highly depends on how interactive the board is and if elements should be animated etc. Is the board rather static, or is the user supposed to select various elements, drag them around etc?

Comment: Iwant to keep it as simple as possible but allow to display images, rather than boxes to click on. But no drag and drop etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a picture using a QLabel widget using the [pixmap property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop). You can check the [detailed information about QPixmap class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qpixmap.html#details) and use links from it to learn which image class (QPixmap, QImage, QBitmap or QPicture) best fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can always just subclass QWidget and override the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` method to draw the board using a QPainter.  (You'd probably also want to override the `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)` and `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)` methods to react to the player's mouse inputs as well; and be sure to call `update()` whenever you want to schedule another call to `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` to redraw the game board)